# Transform NHibernate QueryOver result to Dictionary

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, queryover

I have Nhibernate query that gives me back two columns (string and bool). I want to transform the result into a Dictionary. I know there are Transformers available but I am not sure how to get this working

```
Session.QueryOver<Customer>()
    .Where(x => x.Id == XXX)
    .Select(x => x.Name, x => x.Moderator)
```

Comment: Which is the key in the dictionary? `Name` or `Moderator`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't *think* there's a built in transformer that can do this (you could write your own), but it might be simple enough that writing a bit of LINQ after getting the query results back is good enough.

It depends on what you want your dictionary to look like, but here's an example that might help. Say you wanted to get a dictionary where the key is `true` or `false`, representing moderators and non-moderators, and the value is a `List<string>` with the names of the moderators. In that case you could write:

```
IDictionary<bool, List<string>> moderatorDictionary = session.QueryOver<Customer>()
    .Select(
        x => x.Name,
        x => x.Moderator
    )
    .List<object[]>()
    .GroupBy(x => (bool)x[1], x => (string)x[0])
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.ToList());
```

Using `List<object[]>` usually isn't great for maintainability, but for two properties like this it's probably okay. If you're working with more properties, it's best to create a class and use `AliasToBean` to transform each row into an instance of that class.

Comment: Why are you returning a `IDictionary<bool, List<string>>` should this not just be `IDictionary<bool, string>` and skip the `GroupBy` which I don't think he needs.

Comment: That could certainly be what the OP wants. There's just not enough information in the question to be sure.